# Erro no Django Arte matching query does not exist.

Tags: django

Boa noite, pessoal. Este é meu primeiro post no forum e também sou um pouco leigo em django. Estou desenvolvendo um projeto que envolve um model chamado Arte e em uma das views necessito fazer a atualização de dados. Fiz toda a parte do form e ele chega no template, mas quando clico no botão para salvar as alterações me é apresentado o erro Arte matching query does not exist.

Abaixo segue o código da view. Se precisarem de mais algum, estou a disposição. Desde já, agradeço.

```
def editarte(request):
id_arte = request.GET.get("id")
arte = Arte.objects.get(id = id_arte)
formEditArte = EditArteModelForm(request.POST or None, instance = arte)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if formEditArte.is_valid():
        arte.save()
        return redirect('/editarte')

formEditArte = EditArteModelForm()
context = {
    'formEditArte' : formEditArte,
    'arte': arte
}
return render(request, 'editarte.html', context)
```

Comment: Cleverton, mostra também o HTML do form e o `urls.py` pra eu dar uma olhada em como ta sendo acessado

Answer (score 1):

É possível que o registro que você esteja tentando recuperar por id (id_arte) não exista na base de dados. 
Pelo jeito então, você gostaria de verificar primeiro se o registro existe antes de inserir. Se for esse o caso, coloque esse trecho de código em um bloco **try/except** para tratar a exceção:

```
try:
   arte = Arte.objects.get(id = id_arte)
   // Atualiza o objeto existente
except Arte.DoesNotExist:
   // Cadastre o novo objeto
```

Comment: Na verdade ele já existe. Eu justamente quero editar esse registro existente. No template das artes eu clico num botão abaixo da arte que redireciona para essa view editarte. Ele abre normalmente e consigo preencher o form, mas quando clico em salvar é que o erro acontece.

Comment: Verifica no html gerado se o id do registro a ser editado está definido como um campo hidden. Possa ser que nenhum valor esteja sendo passado nesse parâmetro "id" que você espera no seu script .py.